# Internet control app for Android

Tags: android, internet, battery

I need an app that controls internet access (on-off data connection) to my android phone. 
I want it to enable the internet every 30 minutes or 1 hour when not using my phone and secondly, I want it to enable the internet automatically when I unlock my screen.

Purpose:

1. Get rid of annoying notifications (they can come in regular intervals if there are any)
2. Extend battery life

Is there such app?
Thanks

Comment: Many apps available for that, see my list for [Automation (Profile Switching and more)](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_automation). *Tasker* is probably the most powerful in this context, but not for free. Any budget involved? Do you want an app solely for the purpose described, or are you open to it covering more?

Comment: Tnx @Izzy  I want it for purpose that i don't get annoying notifications all the time and that my phone battery lasts longer. I will update the question with that information. I accept all apps that are free or less than 5$. I will try your Tasker if it does that? Feel free to post your comment as an question. I will try all apps as soon as my new phone arives...

Comment: There you go! I even found your perfect match :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several apps doing exactly what you describe, which I call [Data Stutterer](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_batterysaver#group_510). More precisely, if you only want the listed features, **[AutoData](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.symbuzzer.autodata)** will be perfect:

[image: AutoData] [image: AutoData]
<sup>*AutoData* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.symbuzzer.autodata); click images for larger variants)</sup>

As the screenshots show, this app exactly meets your listed requirements: When the screen is on, data will be enabled – and when it's off, they will be enabled periodically with a configurable interval. All that completely free, of charge and of ads.

If you want more, take a look at apps for [Automation (Profile Switching and more)](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_automation). My favorite here is [Tasker](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info), which is capable of many things (also see my collection of [Tasker Resources](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker)). It's not free (about EUR 3 currently), but worth every cent.