# Automatically enable/disable mobile data mobile on Android devices

Tags: android, battery

Having mobile data enabled all the time drastically reduces the battery life, is there any app to automatically turn on mobile data for 5min and then turn this off for the next hour (and then repeat this every hour)?

Comment: Ui. And I especially pointed you to read something (instead of simply copy-pasting). Did you read it? (Related question on Android.SE: [Automatically enable/disable data mobile](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/143324/16575)). So please [edit] your question here and specify: Android version that must be supported, how much are you willing to pay (or must the app be free)?

Comment: BTW: Search before asking :) [Internet control app for Android](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/27583/185) asks for exactly the same. Or does it lack one feature you didn't mention?

Comment: Yes this answer work for me, thank you @Izzy sorry for that, I search in google but I searched with the wrong terms :(

Comment: Hint: We have a search box here as well (upper-right corner). And you can list questions by tag. You even can combine both, like [`mobile data [android]`](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=mobile+data+[android]) – but I see, that question wouldn't have turned up as it doesn't contain "mobile data" but uses "internet" instead. Well, sh.t happens :) // As that answer works for you (and the questions are similar enough), I hope you don't mind me closing this one as duplicate.